# Member is Null JDA 4.X - Spigot

Tags: discord-jda

### **When running the / verify coderandom
on the console launch Null**
This code was executed in an old version of the JDA

---

```
HashMap<UUID, String> uuidCodeMap =  new HashMap<>();;
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, () -> guild = jda.getGuilds().get(0), 100L);


    
String discordid = uuidIdMap.get(player.getUniqueId());
        //Member is null
        Member target = guild.getMemberById(discordid);
        if (target == null) {
            uuidCodeMap.remove(player.getUniqueId());
            uuidIdMap.remove(player.getUniqueId());
            player.sendMessage("§cError! It seems that you left our Discord server!");
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us you JDABuilder Configuration?

Comment: jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("Null",
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS,
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES,
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES).disableCache(EnumSet.of(
                    CacheFlag.CLIENT_STATUS,
                    CacheFlag.ACTIVITY,
                    CacheFlag.EMOTE